# Eclipse Plugin: Jump to a Line by adding Hyperlink to a row in SWT Table view

Tags: eclipse, hyperlink, eclipse-plugin

The table looks like:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------+
|File Path        |         Line Number   |
|-----------------|-----------------------|
| File1.java      |         10            |
|-----------------|-----------------------|
| File2.java      |         19            |
+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

On double-clicking any row in the table, I want to jump to the the specified line number in the file of its row of the table.

I am using the following function to go to a specified line of an Active Editor.

```java
private static void goToLine(IEditorPart editorPart, int LineNumber)
{
    if (!(editorPart instanceof ITextEditor) || LineNumber <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) editorPart;
    IDocument document = editor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(
            editor.getEditorInput());

    if (document != null)
    {
        IRegion lineInfo = null;

        // line count internally starts with 0, and not with 1 like in GUI
        try
        {
            lineInfo = document.getLineInformation(LineNumber - 1);
        }

        catch (org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (lineInfo != null)
        {
            editor.selectAndReveal(lineInfo.getOffset(), lineInfo.getLength());
        }
      }
    }   
}
```

How to add hyperlinks to the rows of the table to jump to the line of the corresponding file?

Comment: So what is the actual question?

Comment: @greg-449 How to add hyperlink to achieve the "jump to a line" functionality

Answer (score 1):

Adding a hyperlink to a table requires using `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` to draw the table yourself so that you can add the `Hyperlink` controls.

If you just want to support double click on a row you can use `TableViewer.addDoubleClickListener` (or `TableViewer.addOpenListener`) to add an `IDoubleClickListener` (or `IOpenListener`).

Comment: Sir, I have SWT table and I want to add hyperlinks in this table.